# Memory efficient transpose - Awk

Tags: awk, transpose

i am trying to transpose a table (10k rows X 10K cols) using the following script.

A simple data example

$ cat rm1

```
        t1      t2      t3
n1      1       2       3
n2      2       3       44
n3      1       1       1
```

$ sh transpose.sh rm1

```
        n1      n2      n3
t1      1       2       1
t2      2       3       1
t3      3       44      1
```

However, I am getting memory error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
awk -F "\t" '{
for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++)
a[NR, f] = $f
}
NF > nf { nf = NF }
END {
for (f = 1; f <= nf; f++)
for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++)
printf a[r, f] (r==NR ? RS : FS)
}'
```

Error

```
awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=input FNR=12658) fatal: dupnode: r->stptr: can't allocate 10 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)
```

Comment: Well, a hundred million fields are going to take some RAM to cache. Can you tell us something about the data file that could make this easier? If it consisted of only numbers, that would be useful to know, for example. Other than that: How important is speed?

Comment: Maybe some kind of chunking. Cache the first 100 columns and write the first 100 rows. Repeat for the next 100, etc. You can experiment with how big a chunk it can handle without the memory error and set accordingly. This is a great question, I'll be interested to see what people come up with.

Comment: on OS X/BSD you can use `rs -T`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, as I mentioned in my comments, in chunks. Here I show the mechanics on a tiny `12r x 10c` file, but I also ran a chunk of 1000 rows on a `10K x 10K` file in not much more than a minute (Mac Powerbook).6

**EDIT** The following was updated to consider an `M x N` matrix with unequal number of rows and columns. The previous version only worked for an 'N x N' matrix.

```
$ cat et.awk
BEGIN {
    start = chunk_start
    limit = chunk_start + chunk_size - 1
}

{
    n = (limit > NF) ? NF : limit
    for (f = start; f <= n; f++) {
        a[NR, f] = $f
    }
}

END {
    n = (limit > NF) ? NF : limit

    for (f = start; f <= n; f++)
      for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++)
        printf a[r, f] (r==NR ? RS : FS)
}


$ cat t.txt
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 
B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 
C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 


$ cat et.sh
inf=$1
outf=$2

rm -f $outf
for i in $(seq 1 2 12); do
    echo chunk for rows $i $(expr $i + 1)
    awk -v chunk_start=$i -v chunk_size=2 -f et.awk $inf >> $outf
done



$ sh et.sh t.txt t-transpose.txt
chunk for rows 1 2
chunk for rows 3 4
chunk for rows 5 6
chunk for rows 7 8
chunk for rows 9 10
chunk for rows 11 12


$ cat t-transpose.txt 
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 A0 B0 C0
11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 A1 B1 C1
12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92 A2 B2 C2
13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93 A3 B3 C3
14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94 A4 B4 C4
15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95 A5 B5 C5
16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 96 A6 B6 C6
17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87 97 A7 B7 C7
18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88 98 A8 B8 C8
19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99 A9 B9 C9
```

And then running the first chunk on the huge file looks like:

```
$ time awk -v chunk_start=1 -v chunk_size=1000 -f et.awk tenk.txt  > tenk-transpose.txt

real    1m7.899s
user    1m5.173s
sys     0m2.552s
```

Doing that ten times with the next `chunk_start` set to 1001, etc. (and appending with `>>` to the output, of course) should finally give you the full transposed result.

Comment: i just realized if the number of rows are 12k, and columns are 10k, the output is only printing 10k transposed rows as columns. therefore the remaining 2000 are missing. Hope I explained well...

Comment: Yes, I see the problem!  Hopefully I'll have an update for you later today.

Comment: See the edited awk script. There was a bug that was assuming same number of rows and columns.

Comment: This one I'm not able to reproduce. I did a test with 8556 columns and 9192 rows and another with that many columns and 4096 rows (to test ones with both more and less rows than columns). Both tests went okay. How are you calling the awk script?

Comment: you are right. it is working fine. i just run it wrong way. thanks for check again. you are really helpful.

Comment: i just noticed that it is incredibly slow if the rows are like 200k as I can only run 500 rows as a chunk.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple and quick algorithm based on sorting:

1) Make a pass through the input, prepending the row number and column number to each field. Output is a three-tuple of row, column, value for each cell in the matrix. Write the output to a temporary file.

2) Sort the temporary file by column, then row.

3) Make a pass through the sorted temporary file, reconstructing the transposed matrix.

The two outer passes are done by awk. The sort is done by the system sort. Here's the code:

```
$ echo '1 2 3
2 3 44
1 1 1' |
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, NR, $i}' |
sort -n |
awk ' NR>1 && $2==1 { print "" }; { printf "%s ", $3 }; END { print "" }'
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 44 1
```