# Convert Rows to Columns Shell Script

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in the below format

```
APP_OWNER                     : hari
APP_AREA                      : Work:Business Area:AUS
APP_ID                        : 124080
```

I want the data to be converted to below format.

```
APP_OWNER,APP_AREA,APP_ID
hari,Work:Business Area:AUS,124080
```

I can convert one line but how to do it with 3 lines at the same time?

My Attempt with one line

```
sed '0,/: /s//\n/' test.txt
```

Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29081539/4767343

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]+:[[:blank:]]+' '{
   v1 = (v1 == "" ? "" : v1 ",") $1
   v2 = (v2 == "" ? "" : v2 ",") $2
}
END {
   print v1 ORS v2
}' file

APP_OWNER,APP_AREA,APP_ID
hari,Work:Business Area:AUS,124080
```

Comment: I have one more doubt .. suppose if there is more than one set of data then this will not work right ?

Comment: Just updated the data in original question

Comment: That changes your original problem completely. May I suggest you create a new question with new sample data and new requirement. I will try to get a solution for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517884/data-conversion-using-sed-or-awk-name-to-title  -- Created a new Question