# Data Conversion Using Sed or Awk - Name to Title

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in the below format:

```
APP_OWNER                     : hari
APP_AREA                      : Work:Business Area:AUS
APP_ID                        : 124080
APP_OWNER                     : ari
APP_AREA                      : Work:AUS
APP_ID                        : 124345
```

I want the data to be converted to below format.

```
APP_OWNER,APP_AREA,APP_ID
hari,Work:Business Area:AUS,124080
ari,Work:AUS,124345
```

I can convert one line but how to do it with 3 lines at the same time?

My Attempt with one line

```
sed '0,/: /s//\n/' test.txt
```

Original Question : [Convert Rows to Columns Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65497666/convert-rows-to-columns-shell-script?noredirect=1#comment115798136_65497666)

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an `awk` solution without hardcoding any value:

```sh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]+:[[:blank:]]+' 'NR == 1 {fh=$1} !($1 in hdr) {tr = (tr == "" ? "" : tr ",") $1; hdr[$1]} $1 == fh && NR > 1 {print (body ? "" : tr ORS) td; body=1; td=""} {td = (td == "" ? "" : td ",") $2} END {print td}' file

APP_OWNER,APP_AREA,APP_ID
hari,Work:Business Area:AUS,124080
ari,Work:AUS,124345
```

Here is more readable version:

```sh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]+:[[:blank:]]+' '
NR == 1 {
   fh = $1
}
!($1 in hdr) {                    # collect headers only once
   tr = (tr == "" ? "" : tr ",") $1
   hdr[$1]
}
$1 == fh && NR > 1 {              # print header and body
   print (body ? "" : tr ORS) td  # if body=1 then print only body
   body = 1
   td = ""
}
{
   td = (td == "" ? "" : td ",") $2
}
END {
   print td
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]+:[[:blank:]]+' -v OFS="," '
/^APP_OWNER/{
  if(heading){
    count=1
    print heading
  }
  if(val){
    print val
  }
  val=""
}
count=="" && !($1 in head){
  head[$1]
  heading=(heading?heading OFS:"")$1
}
{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$2
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: If there are more than 2 entries title is getting repeated

Comment: @user2854333, your shown samples didn't show this, as I mentioned answers will be given as per shown samples only on SO.

Comment: @user2854333, could you please check my edited one that shouldn't print any heading more than 1 time or so, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
}
!seen[tag]++ {
    tags[++numTags] = tag
}
(NR%3) == 0 {
    if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }

    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    delete tag2val
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
APP_OWNER,APP_AREA,APP_ID
hari,Work:Business Area:AUS,124080
ari,Work:AUS,124345
```